# Why would a server disallow HTTP HEAD?

Tags: http, webserver, http-head

I found out that there are servers that respond with HTTP 405 to `HEAD` requests (or another status code including 404 which is confusing IMO, but that's not important now) even though `GET` requests are responded with HTTP 200. HTTP 405 is [defined](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) as...

> 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the
>   resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an
>   Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested
>   resource.

Alright, I looked at the `Allow` header and found out that I can use `GET` to get the resource (even though I only wanted to find out whether the resource exists). Problem solved.

However, my question is... Why would a server disallow the `HEAD` method? What is the advantage? Are there possible security reasons?

Comment: You wont get a definitive answer I think, one possibility is an attempt to harden the application from attack, if this is worthwhile is subjective - see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/111616/http-head-and-its-security-versus-operational-uses

Comment: Stupidity would be the only reason I'm aware of...

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about disallowed HTTP methods.  In the future, I would suggest asking questions about this topic on [sf] or [security.se].

Answer (score 5):

I think it is because they're getting a log full of "the requested resource can only be accessed via SSL" errors when their HTTPS-only site gets tons of HEAD requests via HTTP. I think they're conflating "method" with "protocol" and so thinking the 405 makes sense.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8532739/353337) for an example of someone asking about the issue and being told to give a 405.