# Avoiding redirect on / in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, load-balancing

I recently had a load balancer added in front of my website.
The loadbalancer will make a HEAD / request, and expect a 200 ok.

Unfortunately, no matter what I do I'm faced with a 302 redirect (to whatever default controller i specify).

This causes the load balancer to believe the website is down.
Unfortunately the load balancer is not something I can configure, or otherwise change behavior.

Quite simply, Whenever a HEAD / request is issued, I would like to return 200 ok.
Preferably only for HEAD requests, to make the load balancer happy.

Any suggestions or ideas for how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps a custom controller and route as described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329101/responding-to-head-request-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: I tried this, but the call is still routed/redirected, and is not answered immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had to use this for a load balancer, but you might look at using `[HttpHead]`. It should be used just like specifying a post action. It might look something like the following:

```
[HttpHead]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: While this will allow me to only act upon head requests, it wouldn't allow me to answer directly to a request, rather than re-routing the call first.